# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE in use of Unirest.post()

Tags: java, exception, unirest

I am using  Unirest.post() for the following simple code :

```
 HttpResponse<String> response = Unirest.post("http://localhost/web/webresources/...")
                    .header("content-type", "application/json")
                    .header("cache-control", "no-cache") 
                    .body("")
                    .asString();
```

and I see the below exception:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.ManagedNHttpClientConnectionFactory.<init>(ManagedNHttpClientConnectionFactory.java:79)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.ManagedNHttpClientConnectionFactory.<init>(ManagedNHttpClientConnectionFactory.java:83)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.ManagedNHttpClientConnectionFactory.<clinit>(ManagedNHttpClientConnectionFactory.java:64)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager$InternalConnectionFactory.<init>(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:522)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:161)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:145)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:117)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:111)
        at com.mashape.unirest.http.options.Options.refresh(Options.java:86)
        at com.mashape.unirest.http.options.Options.<clinit>(Options.java:46)
        at com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpClientHelper.prepareRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:151)
        at com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpClientHelper.request(HttpClientHelper.java:131)
        at `com.mashape.unirest.request.BaseRequest.asString(BaseRequest.java:56)`
```